# JQuery: checked radio button value showing as an empty string

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have the following HTML and JavaScript code

HTML:

```
<label for="oneWay">One Way</label>
<input type="radio" id="oneWay" name="radioOneWayOrReturn" value="oneWay" checked="checked" autocomplete="off" />   
<label for="return">Return</label> 
<input type="radio" id="simpleReturn" name="radioOneWayOrReturn" value="return" autocomplete="off" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function getOneWayOrReturn() {
    return $('input[name="radioOneWayOrReturn"]:checked').val();
}
```

The problem is, when I try and log the result of getOneWayOrReturn(), it shows that the value is an empty string. I'm using JQuery 1.10.3. This is really frustrating, because it should be working but isn't. I can get the id of the checked radio button just fine by using `$(input[name="radioOneWayOrReturn"].prop('id')`, so I know it's finding the right button, but it won't give me the value.

(And no, I can't just use the id because there's another button whose value is also id).

Comment: Appears to be working just fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/s53rd/

Comment: Where are you calling `getOneWayOrReturn`?

Comment: @Saravana: Why does it matter? The point is I'm not getting the value I'm supposed to be getting.

Comment: See its working :- http://jsfiddle.net/P95Vg/

Comment: It matters. I'm assuming this is not all of the code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be snarky. It's because there are multiple places in the code that need that particular value, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

I should give myself a -1 for this. :-(

The radio button set was inside a jqueryUi dialog, and every time I opened it, I called this:

```
$('#dialog').find('input').val('');
```

I've since changed it so that it now reads:

```
$('#dialog').find('input').not(':radio').val('');
```

Normally I'd want to slink away from the humiliation by deleting this question, but I hope instead that someone will somehow stumble across this in the future and learn from my mistake.

Comment: I was doing the exact same thing except I wasn't using JQuery. Haha :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this 1 :-
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P95Vg/2/)

```
function getOneWayOrReturn() {
    var val1 = $('input[name="radioOneWayOrReturn"]:checked').val();
    return val1;
}

$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    var val1 = getOneWayOrReturn();
    alert(val1);
});
```

Comment: OK, this is very strange. I see your jsFiddles are working just fine, but it's still not working in my application.

As for the reason I'm calling the function: this is actually somewhat of a simplification--there's a bunch of other stuff at play here.

Comment: Then you have to chase your code line by line by setting the debugger to find out where the problem is & looking for errors by `Inspect Element`